# shell script rename multi files based on folder ids

Tags: python, shell

ive the following pattern

```
/var/data/file/year/month/day/55122/store/9-833993
```

for 2014 and 2015 i want to rename all files under /store based on the folder ids
here is folder id= 55122  so the file under store should be  9-55122

my problem its not 1 path its multi path like each day of each month will different ids so the patteren will be like this

```
/var/data/file/2014/05/01/55122/store/9-83393393
/var/data/file/2014/05/01/55152/store/9-833993323
/var/data/file/2014/05/01/66122/store/9-83332e4233
/var/data/file/2014/05/02/65122/store/9-833993885
```

etc
 any good way to rename based on ids for any file under store for each day each month ?

Comment: How/where do you get the ID?

Comment: the id is folder name its already exist so no need to get it  , i want to use that id to the name of the file in store dir

Comment: It's still not completely clear to me, can you add a couple of before and after examples?

Comment: sure , here is file before rename                    /var/data/file/2014/05/01/55122/store/9-83393393
file after rename                                           /var/data/file/2014/05/01/55122/store/9-55122

Comment: @jecki you need to rename folder before `store`  or after `store` ??

Comment: rename the file after restore , and the name should as folder before restore starting with 9-folderbeforestore

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

path = "/var/data/file/"

for year in os.listdir(path):
      for month in os.listdir( os.path.join(path,year)):
          for date in os.listdir( os.path.join(path,year,month)):
                   for ran in os.listdir( os.path.join(path,year,month,date):
                         path1 =  os.path.join(path,year,month,date,store)
                                for name in os.listdir(path1):
                                      os.rename( os.path.join(path1,name), os.path.join(path1,"9-"+ran))
```

Comment: If 2014 and 2015 are not only folders in `file` you can use [2014,2015] instead of  `os.listdir(path)`

Comment: You can use `filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path))` for getting only directory's

Comment: lets say here is my  path /var/data/content/images/sys/2011/12/28/781/uploaded/9-92929              and will do it only for 2011 and 2012 all months all days

Comment: got it ill try it and let you know

Comment: id before store is missing , here is valid path for  the actual file ,   /var/data/content/images/sys/2011/12/28/781/uploaded/9-92929   the file should be rename as  /var/data/content/images/sys/2011/12/28/781/uploaded/9-781 you got my point about which part is missing

Comment: @Ravichandra: generally it's recommended to use `os.path.join` instead of `...+'/'+...`

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
 this what i keep getting  here

Comment: ok use `path+'/'+str(year)`  instead of `path+'/'+year`  similarly for month ..etc

Comment: As @wolph said you may use `os.path.join` inserted of string concatenation. Then you will not get this error.